# Yesod application source in a sub directory

Tags: haskell, yesod

I generated a Yesod stub website using `yesod init` and was able to run `yesod devel` for testing. However, I usually put the actual haskell sources in a subdirectory `src` of the main project directory, i.e. one level below the place where the `<project>.cabal` file resides.

However when I moved the yesod site to `src` and changes the cabal file to add the line `hs-source-dir: src`, I got errors similar to the following -

```
src/Model.hs:12:57:
Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
  config/models: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
  Code: persistFile "config/models"
In the second argument of `share', namely
  `$(persistFile "config/models")'
In the expression:
  share
    [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"]
    ($(persistFile "config/models"))
```

Looks like Yesod uses a lot of compile time generated code that requires the path to various directories to be hard coded. What is the best way to fix this problem? What I'd ideally like to do is to not hard code the path to "src" alll over the codebase. Is there someway to read that from the cabal file itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you *could* write some TH code that parses the cabal file to determine the hs-source-dirs, but I think that's excessive. Just prepend a ".." to the filepaths in question. You'll also want to edit Settings and play with the glob function.

Comment: Prepending a '..' will not do the trick. I need to prepend the name of the source folder 'src'. However, if the choice is between that and using TH to parse the cabal file, I guess I'd go with the former.

Comment: You're saying you want to move the config folder into src as well?

Comment: So I finally went with manually specifying the src directory in the source code. However, the TH suggestion is the only real answer to reading cabal files right now.